# fifth time source .zshrc need obvious more time than first time

Tags: zsh, source

Yesterday I was writing a shell script, and need to source .zshrc to update for current zsh shell.

I found the source process need more time as I continue do `source .zshrc`.

The docs of `source` or `.` as belows:

```
. file [ arg ... ]
       Read commands from file and execute them in the current shell environment.

       If file does not contain a slash, or if PATH_DIRS is set, the shell looks in the components of $path to find the directory containing file.  Files in the current  directory
       are  not  read unless `.' appears somewhere in $path.  If a file named `file.zwc' is found, is newer than file, and is the compiled form (created with the zcompile builtin)
       of file, then commands are read from that file instead of file.

       If any arguments arg are given, they become the positional parameters; the old positional parameters are restored when the file is done executing.  However, if no arguments
       are given, the positional parameters remain those of the calling context, and no restoring is done.

       If  file  was  not found the return status is 127; if file was found but contained a syntax error the return status is 126; else the return status is the exit status of the
       last command executed.
source file [ arg ... ]
       Same as `.', except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in $path.
```

---

So question is why source at last need obvious time than beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` (from csh) or `.` (from the Bourne shell) are the builtin commands of the shell that request that shell to `read` and interpret the shell code stored in the file passed as argument.

The time it takes to run is the time it takes to read and interpret that code, so that all depends on what that code does.

For instance, if that code has:

```
var=$var$var
```

Which doubles the size of the `$var` variable every time it is run, it's easy to imagine that the more you run that code, the more time it takes to run it as the amount of data it needs to copy doubles every time you run it.

To find out what command takes most time, you could do:

```
PS4='%D{%T.%3.} %N:%i> '; set -o xtrace; source ~/.zshrc
```

Which would print each command being run with a timestamp with millisecond precision.

Comment: Yeah, that make senses! At least I have `export PATH="/usr/lib/smlnj/bin:$PATH"` in my .zshrc.